# AVPlayer pauses video when it seek to 0.00

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I have used `AVPlayerController` and video is playing without any problem. But when I seek forward till end, **it pauses player and remaining time is 0.00. Notification also not getting fired**.  Also when I resume, it starts from beginning.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                             name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                           object:[avPlayerController.player currentItem]];
```

Even I added `[avPlayer playImmediatelyAtRate:1.0];` but only helped me to overcome stall whenever I slide video.

Any idea ? Is there any delegate to check video completion ?

Comment: Tested in XCode 8.3.2, iOS 10.3